# Not sure how to implement this filter in react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to apply a filter on this chart. [The relevant codesandbox is here:](https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-voice-ww40p?file=/src/App.js)

When user enters input in the box, the chart adjusts accordingly. For instance, If lessThan is selected and 300 is input in the filterLimit box, only bar graph components below 300 will show, like so
[image]
Similarly, if I selected greater than and 300 input in the filterLimit box, only bar graph components above 300 will show.
[image]
I have defined a function in the code applyFilter(value). I am getting confused as to how I will take input from the user and update it with the function to render the appropriate chart.

Comment: Inside you filter method put some logic like to filter the data array and select only those which satisfy the given user value and create graph for those filtered array value only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use state to make your inputs controlled, and use what the user set in filter field and select field in your applyFilter function

see forked sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-newton-dgflo?file=/src/App.js